# Query to find table relationship types

Tags: oracle, entity-relationship

Using Oracle, is there any way I can execute a query to determine what relationship a specific table has with any other tables in my database? I'm fiddling with the `all_constraints` table as of now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this for example:

```
select p.table_name, 'is parent of ' rel, c.table_name
from   user_constraints p
join   user_constraints c on c.r_constraint_name = p.constraint_name
                         and c.r_owner = p.owner
where p.table_name = 'MYTABLE'    
union all
select c.table_name, 'is child of ' rel, p.table_name
from   user_constraints p
join   user_constraints c on c.r_constraint_name = p.constraint_name
                         and c.r_owner = p.owner
where c.table_name = 'MYTABLE'
```

Comment: I'm able to query `all_constraints` but `user_constraints` returns nothing. Other than that, works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is trying to extract as much information as you can from the **foreign key** constraints.

Have a look at [this article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3665591/Finding-Foreign-Key-Constraints-in-Oracle.htm) at Database Journal that explains foreign key data mining in detail.